# how to use Ifram widh CKEditor Rich Text Field?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Use Iframe in VF but in Src there is an CKEditor which use through  php but it not display CKEditor when put that url in VF

Answer (score 0):

this will help you [How To Replace the Salesforce Rich Text Editor](http://macscloud.com/replace-salesforce-rich-text-editor/)